# Do homomorphism that agree on a generating set agree on entire group?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be a groups and $A\subset G_1$ a subset that generates $G$. Suppose that $f, g : G_1 \to G_2$ be homomorphisms such that $f|_A=g|_A$.

Does this imply that $f = g$?

Comment: Yes, and it is easy to show.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: if $f\colon G_1\to G_2$ and $g\colon G_1\to G_2$ are homomorphisms, then the subset $H=\{x\in G_1:f(x)=g(x)\}$ is a …